# I want to fetch contacts stored in Phone but getting problem

Tags: android

i am using following code in order to fetch contacts from Phone 
i am getting names but not number , help me to find out other fields of contacts.

```
public class DialActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mContactList;

public  String[] fields;
 public  Cursor cursor;
 public    boolean mShowInvisible;
 public   Uri uri;
 public   String[] projection;
 public   String[] selectionArgs;
 public  String selection;
 public  String sortOrder;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mContactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

     // Populate the contact list
    populateContactList();




}

   /**
 * Populate the contact list based on account currently selected in the account spinner.
 */
private void populateContactList() {
    // Build adapter with contact entries
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();
    String[] fields = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME

    };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.TextView01});
    mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * Obtains the contact list for the currently selected account.
 *
 * @return A cursor for for accessing the contact list.
 */
private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +
            (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

}

In the above code i am using a custom ListRow layout and showing the contact name in each row, but want to populate a list which has names and corresponding number so that i can make a call on those number by clicking on that listItem. I know how to make call but i am not having the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContactsContract.Contacts doesn't contain the phone number but you have the id of the contacts so you can now query `ContactsContract.Data` to get the phone number. A sample query can be found at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Comment: tried it, but passing null results in NullPointerException  :(